# <dl> <dt> <dd> <li> dropdown getting information with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list that looks something like this. I need help getting information from the current selection using javascript. What id's and whatever appropriate javascript call would I need to add to get the "value" of the currently selected

```
<dl id="order" class="dropdown">
  <dt><a href="#"><span>(Name of Selected Item Ends up here)</span></a></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul style="z-index: 1000; display: none; ">
      <li value="1"><a href="1">Item 1</a></li>
      <li value="2"><a href="2">Item 2</a></li>
      <li value="3"><a href="3">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
    });

    $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
        $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        if(order != getSelectedValue("order")) {
        order = getSelectedValue("order");
        }
    });

    function getSelectedValue(id) {
        return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
    }

    $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Do the list items have a click handler? Any javascript code you've written already?

Comment: Yeah, I added the javascript that I think you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking, this will return the value of the list item that is clicked:

```
$(this).closest('li').attr('value');
```

You could then remove the getSelectedValue function.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KKgWv/)**